# MacOs App Store pkg Productbuild -- add a property to product list (without Xcode)

Tags: macos, properties, pkgbuild, productbuild

Dear macOS Productbuild and pkgbuild experts (without/not using the Xcode)

This is my last hurdle after going through a huge learning journey on product build and pkgbuild

I get the error from Appstore

- "ITMS-90264: The lowest minimum system version [none] in the Product
  Definition Property List must equal the 'LSMinimumSystemVersion'
  value [10.9] in the 'Info.plist'. "

In my App/Contents/Info.Plist there is

```
`<key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
  <string>10.9</string>`
```

Now when I build the package as per the following sequence

```
 `pkgbuild --analyze --root "./pkgbuild/app_path/" app.plist
    
    pkgbuild --root "${ROOTFOLDER}" --identifier "${IDENTIFIER}" --version ${VERSION} --    component-plist ./app.plist  --install-location "/Applications" \
     --sign "${IDENTITY}" \
     "${PKGNAME}.pkg"
    
    #productbuild --synthesize --package Final.pkg distribution.xml
    
    productbuild --distribution ./distribution.xml --resources ~/Desktop/resources --identifier com.myorg.uniqueid --version ${VERSION} --sign "${IDENTITY}" --product ~/Desktop/modInfo.plist outputFinal.pkg`
```

Question Where do I incorporate the the lowest minimum system version none in the Product Definition Property List " to 10.9 ? and what do I need to insert in what file, how?

Deeply appreciate if I can get some pointers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for responding. I did look at that link earlier. Excuse, I am super newbie for this.. I  added  <key>os</key>
    <string>10.9</string> in the modInfo.plist as an argument to product build --product modInfo.plist but did not get the result.. appsotore still complains I don't have the minimum system version. Any further pointers, much much appreciated!

Comment: I posted an answer, hopefully that'll steer you in the right direction. Basically you need a `production_definition.plist` to accompany your `productbuild` command with the minimum os version set in there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a `product_definition.plist` with the minimum os version. It should look similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>os</key>
  <array>
    <string>10.9.0</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Your `productbuild` command would become:

```
productbuild \
    --distribution ./distribution.xml \
    --resources ~/Desktop/resources \
    --identifier com.myorg.uniqueid \
    --version ${VERSION} \
    --sign "${IDENTITY}" \
    --productbuild --product ~/Desktop/product_definition.plist --component build/Release/Your.app /Applications outputFinal.pkg
```

So basically we've changed your `modInfo.plist` to the correct name (`product_definition.plist`) and included the key to handle the minimum os version.

Comment: The key was incorrect apparently; try the one in the updated answer. If the new key doesn't work it might be `os-version` that is needed along with `min`. Apple's docs are a bit outdated unfortunately and it's not entirely clear.

Comment: You might want to try `<string>10.9.0</string>` instead of just `<string>10.9</string>`. It's a small detail, but could possibly be the issue.

Comment: @I'L'I after some grueling debug, I noticed when I have --distribution option, the --product product_definition is ignored. I test with --product no_file_exists with --distrubtion distribution.xml it went ahead created package. When I remove --ditsribution option and have --product no_file_exists productbuild throws error correctly that "No product definition plist found at "no_file_exists".  First not sure why? Is there a way to include product requirements in distribution.xml? Appreciate any pointers/direction. Been a week, I am bumping into wall. Please.

Comment: @tech_geek: Yes, there are ways you can actually script product requirements into the distribution and/or create plugins that handle it, although whether the AppStore would accept those methods is an entirely different story. For your project I believe we've been misinformed by our research and perhaps using outdated methods. I noticed on the `productbuild` manual page they mention that a PRE-INSTALL PROPERTY LIST replaced the `product_definition.plist` supposedly. It still uses a property list but they show it used with `--component` (see next comment).

Comment: This is the syntax they show in the man page: `productbuild --product def.plist --component build/Release/Sample.app /Applications Product.pkg`, so def.plist would be the `product_defintion.plist` we've created.  "Build the archive Product.pkg to install Sample.app under /Applications, synthesizing a distribution with the requirements from def.plist. This is typical for building a Mac App Store archive with pre-install requirements.". The key they show is `os` to handle the minimum version in the top example of the answer.

Comment: @I'L'I Thanks and I had success yesterday with --product and --component options ; Appstore accepted the build. I will go ahead and accept your answer. Now I have a different problem -- lost ability to include a license file (Eula) -used to do with distribution.xml ; Is there any way I can include the Eula with --component option? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @tech_geek: You're welcome! I'm glad you finally got the minimum os version sorted. I'm not understanding how you were implementing the EULA previously and why you no longer have the ability to include it. Apple might have some restrictions on that as well regarding the placement (within your app, outside of it, etc.) so you might want to check.

Comment: @I'L'I I used to have this <license file="eula.txt" /> in the distribution.xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224032/discussion-between-lll-and-tech-geek).

Answer (score 1):

To conclude this thread, and for help to future queries on this very topic, here is a summary

1. productbuild with both options --distribution distribution.xml and --product product_definition.plist do not work together -- I am using 10.15.7 Catalina MacOS ; product definition is ignored
2. Ended up using --component component path with --product product_definition.plist to get accepted by Appstore
3. Since from step 2, I am now without distribution.xml, I lost license/eula ability

I decided to address Eula in my app itself under the menu.

My deepest thanks to I'L'I for patient pointers

Too many hassles with AppStore and little documentation and running around in cycles is not worth the time. Thanks Apple!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `--distribution ./distribution.xml`

You need to add `<os-version min="10.9"/>` to the distribution.xml file

see: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Distribution_XML_Ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005370-CH100-SW33